# Getting error when changing the coordinates of region on react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am getting an error **"You attempted to set the key `latitude` with the value `xx.xxxxx` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen** when my app starts or when i try to change the coordinates of the region via callback funciton.

My goal is to be able to change the region location from input field like on Google Maps. But whenever i change the coordinates i get this error. I tried with rerendering the map with the new coordinates and that works, but that will do lots of requests.

Is there a way of giving the region new coordinates and showing it without rerendering the whole map ?

**Here is my code:**

```
export default class Map extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
      },
      radius: 500
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){

  }

  regionChange = (region) =>{
    let reg = this.state.region;
    reg.latitude = region.latitude;
    reg.longitude = region.longitude;
    this.setState({region:reg});
  }

  changeRadius = (radius) => {
    this.setState({radius});
    console.log("RADIUS", this.state.radius);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={ styles.map }>
        <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={ styles.map }
            region={this.state.region}
            onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => {this.regionChange(region)}}
            onPress={(event) => this.regionChange(event.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
        >
          <MapView.Circle
            center = { this.state.region }
            radius = { this.state.radius }
            strokeWidth = { 1 }
            strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
            fillColor = { 'rgba(230, 238, 255, 0.5)' }
            onRegionChangeComplete = {(region) => {this.regionChange({region});console.log(region)}}
          />
          <Marker
            coordinate = { this.state.region }
            title = {"Marker"}
            description = {"Marker description"}
          />
        </MapView>
        <Slider
          step={50}
          maximumValue={2000}
          onValueChange={(value) => this.changeRadius(value)}
          value={this.state.radius}
          style={{marginTop:10}}
        />
        <Autocomplete regionChange={(reg) => this.regionChange(reg)} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not primitive data types. So, they are passed by value by reference. In your code when you did `let reg = this.state.region` you have made a reference to this.state.region. So, when you mutate reg, you mutate state directly which is a big no in react.

I suggest you to use spread operator to make a new copy of state.
`let reg = { ...state, {} }`

Comment: You're welcome now please tick mark this as answer so that this post can close. :)